# doxygen tag file directory

Tags: html, tags, doxygen

I am using .tag files for making documentation of my packages. The top package uses source files from the bottom package, and the .html docs also refer back to the base package. The two packages are in two different (parallel) subdirectories, and the .tag file nicely delivers the anchors to the top package, except that it is assumed that the .html files of the bottom package are in the same subdirectory, i.e. together with the .html files of the top package.
The subdirectory information is provided with the location of the .tag file, 
so maybe I missed to switch some flag, or I do need to merge the two .html subdirectories, or have the same .dox subdirectory for the two packages?  I.e.: how to use it?
My structure:

```
BASIC
-- doc (with documentation-config.doxygen.in, 
  comprising "GENERATE_TAGFILE       =  @CMAKE_BINARY_DIR@/doc/BASIC.tag"
and "OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = @CMAKE_BINARY_DIR@/doc"
-- build
```

and in parallel

```
TOP
-- doc (with documentation-config.doxygen.in, comprising
   "TAGFILES =  @CMAKE_BINARY_DIR@/../../BASIC/build/doc/BASIC.tag"
as well as
   "GENERATE_TAGFILE  =  @CMAKE_BINARY_DIR@/doc/TOP.tag"
```

(Yes, I have a third level, too, so I need to generate a tag file.
BASIC and TOP have different CMake files)

A related problem: in both directories I have a include/Config.h file, where the file in the TOP has the lines

```
// Take over basic configuration
#include "../../../BASIC/modules/include/Config.h"
```

Doxygen is right with saying that  "@file Config.h" can refer to any of the two 'Config.h' files, but either the error message is not quite proper (it asks for 'more details') or I could not figure out whether I shall type out the full relative part or I am allowed to supply in some shorter form the place of the right file.

As far as I understand, it is something else, but somewhat related. Doxygen runs OK, but after that I wnat to make a .chm docs, using

```
chmcmd, a CHM compiler. (c) 2010 Free Pascal core.
```

It compiles, but presents with a warning that

```
Warning: Found file namespacestd.html ..., but couldn't find it on disk
```

My guess is that is it not the dust of Doxygen, but can I do something on the Doxygen side, to suppress that warnings? (I guess it is related to "using namespace std;")

Comment: At first instance looks OK, but to find the problem we at least need the setting you used in both packages in respect to the tag files as well as the directory structure of the relation between the base and main package

Comment: OK, but we may use the reversed approach: you say what was supposed, i.e. how shall I use it. I add to the question the structure.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation of the TAGFILES and here you will find that you can also specify  the place of the  HTML files (see also the chapter Linking to external documentation).

Comment: @albert Thanks, that was I was missing.

Comment: So the original tag problem has been solved. Looks like you added also a "related problem" this won't be noticed (and there shouldn't be multiple problems in one question. Please create a new question for it. Important is also to know which version of doxygen are you using? How do you create the chm file (from within doxygen, separately) and is this for the base or main directory. I vaguely remember that the mentioned file did give some problems. Also Notice that tag files are nor really suited for CHM as they refer to another file (chm), same accounts for LaTeX, rtf etc.

Comment: @albert Sorry for 'hiding' another question in the original one. I am working under Ubuntu, so I cannot use the original Windows compiler, even if it is partly supported by Doxygen. In addition, I experienced "memory overflow" issue when using the Free Pascal compiler with the .tag file, and also I found that in the form I attempted to solve, using .tag files leads to problem when making LaTeX documentation. So, I decided to use the source files directly, rather than through .tag files. Thanks for your help.